# If $x + y = 5xy$ , $y + z = 6yz$ , $z + x = 7zx$ . Find $x + y + z$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, problem-solving

> If $x + y = 5xy$ , $y + z = 6yz$ , $z + x = 7zx$ . Find $x + y + z$ .

**What I Tried** :

I used some clever ways to get $x + y + z = 26xyz$ , but I suppose we have some solution as a number .

All all $3$ to get :-

$$2(x + y + z) = 5xy + 6yz + 7zx$$
Or,
$$ 2(x + y + z) = (xy + xy + xy + xy + xy) + (yz + yz + yz + yz + yz + yz) + (zx + zx + zx + zx + zx + zx + zx)$$
That is,
$$ 2(x + y + z) = (xy + zx) + (xy + zx) + (xy + zx) + (yz + zx) + (yz + zx) + (yz + zx) + (yz + zx) + (xy + yz) + (xy + yz)$$

Now see that $(xy + zx) = x(y + z) = 6xyz$ , similarly $(yz + zx) = 5xyz$ and $(xy + yz) = 7xyz$

So
$$2(x + y + z) = 3(6xyz) + 4(5xyz) + 2(7xyz)$$

$$\Rightarrow (x + y + z) = \frac{52xyz}{2} = 26xyz$$

I tried till this , then I have no idea . Can anyone help?

Comment: Divide by $xy$, $yz$ and $zx$ respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming $x,y,z \neq 0$, we have that,

$$x + y = 5xy \iff \frac1x+\frac1y =5$$

$$y + z = 6yz \iff \frac1y+\frac1z =6$$

$$z + x = 7zx \iff \frac1z+\frac1x =7$$

then solve for $1/x$, $1/y$, $1/z$.

The case $x=0 \lor y=0 \lor z=0$ is trivial.

Comment: Ok that looks like a good answer , but how to solve it ? I mean adding all 3 would give $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} = 9$ , which is $xy + yz + zx = 9xyz$

Comment: @SouradipDas Solve as a linear system in $X=1/x$, $Y=1/y$, $Z=1/z$. We should obtain $X=3$, $Y=2$, $Z=4$.

Comment: Or just subtract the first equation to get $\frac{1}{z} = 9-5= 4$, so $z = \frac{1}{4}$, and similarly for the other equations.

Comment: Aah ok ok fine you mean find values for $X,Y,Z$ and then get $x + y + z$ .

Comment: @SouradipDas Exactly, that seems the simpler way to me!

Comment: That's the same thing in disguise.

Comment: @PopularPower Yes of course, my comment was about the general method. For solve the linear system your way is very fine.

Answer (score 4):

Taking @user's hint a little further (and also assuming $x,y,z,\neq 0$), writing
\begin{align}
u &=\frac{1}{x}\\
v&=\frac{1}{y}\\
w&=\frac{1}{z}
\end{align}
Yields
\begin{align}
u+v &= 5\\
v+w &= 6\\
z+u&=7
\end{align}
thus
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v\\
w\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
5\\
6\\
7
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v\\
w\\
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
5\\
6\\
7
\end{pmatrix}$$
Whence
$$\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v\\
w\\
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
6\\
4\\
8\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And returning to the representation of these $u, v, w$ in terms of $x, y, z$ gives the desired result.

Comment: Don't forget the trivial solution $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: @user Oh fine, I'll write that but was following on from your hint wihch assumed that this solution is notwithstanding.....

Comment: well using this for such a simple system is a little bit overkill in my opinion

Comment: @Kevin That's fine, I only give a suggestion to make the answer complete. I also gave the solution by a comment but solved mentally! Bye

Comment: @PopularPower Overkill is probably right, however I wanted to further a comment that advances the discussion, rather than following the usual algebraic manipulations the other answer's offer.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply both sides of $x+y=5xy$, $y+z=6yz$ and $z+x=7zx$ by $z,x$ and $y$ respectively and add them together to obtain:

$xz+zy+xy+xz+zy+xy=2(xz+zy+xy)=18xyz$ so $xz+zy+xy=xy+z(x+y)=xy+5xyz=9xyz$.

So $xy=4xyz$ and hence $z=\frac{1}{4}$, etc.